# Выдает ошибку при импортировании Gradle проекта в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

После нажатия `File` -> `Import` -> `Gradle` -> `Gradle Project` выдает следующую ошибку:

```
No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.ui.internal.emptyEditorTab
```

При нажатии `Details...` выводит на экране следующее:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createErrorPart(EditorReference.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:342)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1209)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)
```

Что делать в таком случае и как исправить ошибку?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933348/eclipse-could-not-open-the-editor-no-editor-descriptor-for-id-org-eclipse-jdt